# Show different data in 2 separate JTables

Tags: java, arrays, swing

The Array data[][] stores the right values inside the loop.
Then I add the array to an ArrayList, but it's like all objects inside the ArrayList are being updated when I change the value of my data array after that.

How can I store the value of each Object[][] separately?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Materia.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Materia[i].Aluno.length; j++) {                
            data[j][0] = Materia[i].Aluno[j].Nome;
            System.out.println(data[j][1] = Materia[i].Aluno[j].Nome);//checking outpit, its displaying the correct data I want
            data[j][1] = Materia[i].Aluno[j].nota;
            data[j][2] = Materia[i].Aluno[j].frequencia;
        }
        tabs.add(data);  //arraylist to storer object data          
        tabela[i] = new JTable((Object[][]) tabs.get(i), Names);//populate default table model
        conteudo2[i] = new JPanel();
        conteudo2[i].add(new JLabel(Materia[i].Nome));            
        conteudo2[i].add(new JScrollPane(tabela[i]));

    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be in the Arraylist?

Comment: I want the object[][] data in the same state when i add it ArrayList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add your data array (of arrays) to the tab-List.

Since you don't create a new object before adding it to the arrayList, it's the same object, and therefore you also update the contents in the data-Array, when you update the object in the tab-List.

You need to create a new data-Array, before adding it to the list.

You can achieve this by creating a new 2d-Array with the method System.arrayCopy before you add this new object to you tabs-List:

```
Object[][] myDataCopy = new Object[data.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    myDataCopy[i] = new XXYY[d.length];
    System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, myDataCopy[i], 0, data[i].length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, trying to understand and implement on my code

Comment: I can't understand what dMatrix is.  Looking around I figured it is probably TypeofData[] d, at least I understood the concept, but still have to implement it right.